# Is there any way to send a raw signed transaction via ethers?

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, nodejs

I want to send a signed transaction with ethers through a provider, but the `sendTransaction` method does not exist anywhere besides the `Wallet` object. I basically want to do something like this:

```
    const provider = new JsonRpcProvider("https://coston-api.flare.network/ext/C/rpc")

    const signedTx = Transaction.from({
        data: unsignedTx.data,
        to: unsignedTx.to,
        gasLimit: unsignedTx.gasLimit,
        gasPrice: unsignedTx.gasPrice,
        nonce: unsignedTx.nonce,
        signature: {
            r: resp.r.toString('hex'),
            s: resp.s.toString('hex'),
            v: resp.recoveryParam!
        }
    })

    // send transaction
    await provider.sendTransaction(signedTx)
```

I know I can use web3, or call the node API directly, but I want this to be ethers-encapsulated. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `send` function of the provider as per the docs: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/#JsonRpcProvider-send.